# Set css attribute in onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with set `fontStyle` attribute to single element(by `id`) in popover. I get `onClick` event, put style (`bold` font style) to all class elements and then try to put another style(`normal`) to one(clicked) element. My code is:

```
$(document).on('click', '.listElement', function () {
    $('.listElement').css('font-weight', 'bold');
    alert(this.id);
    $(this).css('font-weight', 'normal');
});
```

There is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/knh7qprw/)

Setting `bold` style for all class elements works and dialog shows correctly `id` so this is right element(in `this`) but `.css()` method doesn't work. I tried to put style by using `id` like:

```
$('#A').css('font-weight', 'normal');
```

and there is no error in console but it doesn't work as well. Is there any other way to set fontStyle to single unique element?

Comment: Your code is actually working. But when the popover closes on click on it or outside and opens again the plugin re initialises the font to the initial state.

Comment: @DanPhilip I'm not sure but probably you are wrong because there is not initial state. In page load is `normal` font style for all elements and after first click(on any element) there is `bold` style for all.

Comment: the problem is, you redirect to your page every time you click on a link and the complete code runs from begin. if you want to save the click state you have to store it in sessionStorage and request on script begin. try it without links and you will see the css works. another option is to write a single side application with MVC and listening on hashChange event. (I'm working on a tutorial for that)

Comment: @TypedSource so why set font style for elements by class works?

Comment: @barmi because you don't reload your page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than removing CSS styling why not just never add it to the clicked object??

Get the ID of the clicked object and use that...

```
$(document).on('click', '.listElement', function () {
var clickEl = this.id; //ID of clicked object
$('.listElement').not('#' + clickEl).css('font-weight', 'bold'); //bolds everything which is NOT the clicked item.
alert(this.id);
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('click', '.listElement', function () {
$('.listElement').not('#' + this.id).css('font-weight', 'bold'); //bolds everything which is NOT the clicked item.
alert(this.id);
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/knh7qprw/4/)

---

if there is a specific reason you need to remove the styling rather than never applying it...

```
$(document).on('click', '.listElement', function () {
$('.listElement').css('font-weight', 'bold');
alert(this.id);
$('.listElement#' + this.id).css('font-weight', 'normal');
});
```

[**Fiddle for that**](http://jsfiddle.net/knh7qprw/7/)